# How to search strings with brackets using Regular expressions

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I have a case wherein I want to search for all `Hello (World)` in an array. Hello (World) is coming from a variable and can change. I want to achieve this using RegExp and not `indexOf` or `includes` methods.

```
testArray = ['Hello (World', 'Hello (World)', 'hello (worlD)']
```

My match should return index 1 & 2 as answers.

Comment: What is expected output>

Comment: Should it be case-insensitive? If not then it should be just index 1.

Comment: Should be case insensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `RegExp` constructor after escaping the string (algorithm from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/10221765)), and use some array methods:

```js
const testArray = ['Hello (World', 'Hello (World)', 'hello (worlD)'];
const string = "Hello (World)".replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
const regex = new RegExp(string, "i");
const indexes = testArray.map((e, i) => e.match(regex) == null ? null : i).filter(e => e != null);
console.log(indexes);
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, `Hello (World)` is coming from a variable and can change :(

Comment: Copy/paste error from testing environment, fixed @melpomene.

Comment: If you just want to see whether a regex matches, `regex.test(e)` might be more efficient.

Comment: It works though - just replace `"Hello (World)"` with the name of the variable.

Answer (score -1):

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/5eUuO8/1/) might help you to do so:

```
(\w+)\s\((\w+)
```

You may not need to bound it from left and right, since your input strings are well structured. You might just focus on your desired capturing groups, which I have assumed, each one is a single word, which you can simply modify that.

With a simple string replace you can match and capture both of them.

[image]

#### RegEx Descriptive Graph

This graph shows how the expression would work and you can visualize other expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### Performance Test

This JavaScript snippet shows the performance of that expression using a simple 1-million times `for` loop.

```js
repeat = 1000000;
start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 var string = "Hello (World";
 var regex = /(\w+)\s\((\w+)/g;
 var match = string.replace(regex, "$1 & $2");
}

end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention, `Hello (World)` is coming from a variable and can change

Comment: None of this even attempts to answer the question. But nice emojis, I guess?

Comment: Just because you misunderstood the question doesn't mean you can just edit OP's question to make your answer fit. Edit your answer so it applies to OP's question, not the other way round.

Answer (score -2):

```js
testArray = ['Hello (World', 'Hello (World)', 'hello (worlD)'];
let indexes = [];
testArray.map((word,i)=>{
  if(word.match(/\(.*\)/)){
    indexes.push(i);
  }
});
console.log(indexes);
```

Comment: This doesn't search for a user-specified string (case insensitively), like OP wants.